# What is the semantics of WebCore::HTMLEmbedElement::updateWidget?

Tags: android, webkit

I am quite fresh to Webcore of webkit. There is no much time for me to study webkit from the beginning. But my project requires me to do some modifications to Webcore:: HTMLEmbedElement::updateWidget.  Would you please give some hints about its semantics and related operations that invoke its??? tks indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It's to update the embed element's view, mostly it's for plugin, such as Flash